# Google Cloud Platform Debugger for Compute Engine with Payara/Glassfish Application Server

Tags: java, debugging, google-cloud-platform, glassfish

I started an Ububtu VM on google cloud platform that contains a payara application server (a fork of Glassfish) and everything works great. The deployed app is a bunch of WAR files.
Now I would like to debug the live application with google cloud debugger.
I tried to implement the manual's instructions from [here](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/java#gce) and added support for war files as described [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-java/blob/master/README.md).

Yet, whenever I tried to take a debug snapshot the live application using files from my local computer and the war files I uploaded to my application server  the debugger kept a problem occurred. The problem was that the debugger said it can't find the file in the executable.

I also tried to upload the sources to my VM compile them and deploy them to the application server. It didn't also work.

Does anyone have a working scenario where I can deploy war files to a Glassfish/Payara server and debug it within a VM on Google cloud platform?

Answer (score 0):

Could you test it on a 64-bit Debian Linux image with Java JDK version 7, 8 or, 9?
Those seems to be a [requisite](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/java#gce) for GCE.